# Windows Phone Company Hub App - Can't overwrite/update existing Apps

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I have built a Company Hub App to download and install other Apps for Windows Phone 8.1. The installation of the certified XAP Packages works fine with InstallationManager.AddPackageAsync().

When the App is already installed and I want to install it again, lets say a newer Version, I get the Error: Exception from HRESULT: 0x81030137. Is there a possibility to get this handled? If I uninstall the App and then try to install it again it works fine. But I'd like to have the Company App as an Update Portal without manually deleting old Apps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and then I noticed that I had wrong Publisher ID in WMAppManifest.xml.
I changed that, published the signed version to the phone and then when I tried to update again with another later version it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the system exception with respective `HRESULT` value:

```
catch (Exception ex) 
{
  int hr = ex.HResult;
  if (hr == -2130509513 )
  {
    // the application is already installed
  }
}
```

Similarly, if you want to handle a scenario where in you are trying to upload an older version of an app but a latest version is already installed you can catch the exception in similar way as above with *HRESULT value as -2147009274*.

In case you are trying to update your app with newer version you can store apps and their respective versions in a dictionary, and compare the incoming version with the existing version and update if incoming version is greater than existing version.